# Does code in onHandleIntent block IntentService from receiving other intents?

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, blocking, intentservice

I have a `IntentService` that connects to bluetooth (blocking part), sends data, and disconnects. I have modified `IntentService` to handle a special intent that will stop the service. However, it seems that because of blocking code, which connects to a bluetooth device (indefinitely or until canceled by user, as intended), the overriden onStart or onStartCommand is not called untilthe blocking part of code is no longer blocking.

Could the code inside onHandleIntent be blocking other intents reaching the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. IntentService uses a single worker thread.

Or to quote the docs exactly:

> All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as
>   long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop),
>   but only one request will be processed at a time.

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

This means that only one call to `onStartCommand` can be happening on the IntentService at a time.

Comment: In my case, application can send data only after connection was made. Would it be considered a normal practice to have a connecting thread inside onHandleIntent which will send a message to Handler with a go or no-go message? Something like this http://pastebin.com/9BuSPNv4

Comment: No, if you're using an IntentService, you shouldn't really be starting your own threads in there. Or rather, it sounds like what you really want to use is a normal Service, and start your own worker thread there, using whatever you want (AsyncTask, HandlerThread, Executor etc)